# Working with accounts and data

Tags: meteor, accounts

In the next phase of my chat room application I want to work with user accounts.

I want to do the following.

1. Require user to create an account or login to post a message (when logged out the message area will be replaced with a bootstrap alert box)
2. Once logged in, the name field will use the username

It would also be nice to allow users to set their username rather than it be their email address.

I have been looking through questions and the parties tutorial but I have not yet been able to reverse engineer the functionality in my instance. Would anyone be willing to assist me?

Project files - https://github.com/SmashBrando/chatroom

Project - http://smashchat.meteor.com/

Answered:

To display content if the user is logged in I added:

```
        {{#if currentUser}}
           {{> entry}}
        {{else}}
           <div class="alert alert-error">
            You Must Login To Post a Message!
           </div>
        {{/if}}
```

To set the username as the message name (the profile name a user wants to be known as) I added the following code to the input area.

`<input type="text" class="span6" id="name" value="{{currentUser.username}}">`

I will be working on a future iteration that does not use the input box and uses a variable (once I figure out how to do that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the handlebars helper and if/else to show certain items

```
{{#if currentUser}}
   <logged in content>
{{else}}
   <not logged in content>
{{/if}}
```

for the user's name, you'll have to use another field for their real name, usually within the profile eg. `user.profile.name`

assuming the user's name has been set, you should then be able to do something like

```
{{#if currentUser}}
   {{loginButtons}}
{{else}}
   {{currentUser.profile.name}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: This seems to be working. In my case I have not set a username. Can you explain how to get that setup when using accounts UI?

Comment: I found adding the following gave me a username field but I am having trouble getting it to output in my template.

`Accounts.ui.config({
  passwordSignupFields: 'USERNAME_ONLY'
});`

Comment: To clarify I want to be able to login using the username (which I accomplished)

Now I want that username to be used as the message name. I want this to me attached with the message.

Comment: I have resolved this. I have updated my git and demo.

The solution was to place the username in the form using {{currentUser.username}}

I am working on making it so this is not in a form and dis set when inserting the entry.